# Azure Devops Nuget Restore Task fails

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have Inherited an project with more or less 71 projects in one solutions.
I am currently trying to setup an CI/CD pipeline.

While setting up the the build process i realized there is an private nuget package. So i added in the the NuGet.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="ASI" value="http://private:8989/nuget/private-Libraries" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Also installed an agent on one of the boxes. So i was hoping that if i use the agent that i installed i would not need to worry about the private nuget package...But seems like it cant resore any of the packages.

Keep getting the following error

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects
>       Unable to find version '1.9.0' of package 'Someprivatepackage'.
>         https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Someprivatepackage.1.9.0' is not found on source
>   'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
>         http://private:8989/nuget/private-Libraries: Package 'Someprivatepackage.1.9.0' is not found on source
>   ' http://private:8989/nuget/private-Libraries'.)
>
> Packages failed to restore

How can i restore these packages, I assume its because its behind a VPN of some sorts.

Comment: According to the error message `Package 'Someprivatepackage.1.9.0' is not found on source ' http://private:8989/nuget/private-Libraries'`, it shows package not found rather then can not access the source. So, please make sure your package **Someprivatepackage** with version **1.9.0** in that package Sources.

Comment: That's true, let me try and figure out if it is...ill keep you posted

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Comment: OK, so after some investigation, i realized that i needed to build another project before the project that i wanted to build. This works great locally, But i see there is no easy way in Azure Devops to have one build rely on another?

Comment: If the another project in the same solution, you can add the project reference and build the solution file instead of project file directly. Or you can add a another build task in your pipeline to build the another project first.

Comment: It is actually in a different repository.

Comment: um, this is key point. In this case, you are right. There is no easy way in Azure Devops to have one build rely on another. Since you have find the reason and resolve this issue for this issue, could you please share your solution as answer, so that we could archive this case? Thanks.